# Does $(A = v_a \implies B = v_b) \implies P(B = v_b) \geq P(A = v_a)$ make sense?

Tags: probability, logic, random-variables

I have a question regarding the following formula:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two random variables.
>
> If $A = v_a \implies B = v_b$, then
>
> $\mathcal{P}(B = v_b) \geq \mathcal{P}(A = v_a)$

I was told that the hypothesis ($A = v_a \implies B = v_b$) does not make sense mathematically speaking, specifically, that the hypothesis should not contain an implication and that I should try to define this formula in another way, perhaps defining $v_b$ as a function of $v_a$. I think the formula is correct, but I was not able to find a source in which this formula (or a similar one) appears. I want to know how to show that it makes sense to have a conditional statement ($\implies$) in the hypothesis of a formula. Ideally, the formula I am interested in could be mentioned in some source. Unfortunately, I was not able to find it. I have already checked out these sources [1][2][3][4] to no avail, in addition to a search in this forum.

My question is: does this formula make sense? and if it does, which books/papers/or other sources can I check to verify it?

[1] Giangiacomo Gerla (1994). Inferences in probability logic, Artificial Intelligence, 70(1), 33 - 52.

[2] Nils J. Nilsson (1986). Probabilistic logic, Artificial Intelligence, 28(1), 71 - 87.

[3] H. T. Nguyen, M. Mukaidono, & V. Kreinovich (2002). Probability of implication, logical version of Bayes theorem, and fuzzy logic operations. In 2002 IEEE World Congress on Computational Intelligence. 2002 IEEE International Conference on Fuzzy Systems. FUZZ-IEEE'02. Proceedings (Cat. No.02CH37291) (pp. 530-535 vol.1).

[4] https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-probability/#CombLogiProbTheo

Comment: Why no implication? Perhaps replacing $\implies $ with $\to $ satisfies some schools of logicians ...

Comment: I was told that having an implication in the hypothesis does not make sense, regardless of the symbol used. But I will change the symbol just in case, because in the sources I provided they also seem to prefer that symbol.

Comment: Your hypothesis can be written more formally in the language of **events**:  $$\{A = v_a\} \subseteq \{V = v_b\}$$ which indeed means that $$P[A = v_a] \leq P[V = v_b]$$

Comment: Thanks, I think that this is also a valid solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally wrote the hypothesis without a conditional, by using probabilities. I used the following equivalent hypothesis.

$$\mathcal{P}(b = v_b | a = v_a) = 1$$

I still don't know if an implication in the hypothesis is correct or not, but at least I know that this one is correct.